# Programmatically create a JSF HtmlOutputLink

Tags: java, jsf-2

Using JSF java classes, is it possible to programmatically create a link which passes a parameter another page.

```
<h:link value="Edit" outcome="edit" >
    <f:param name="id" value="500" />
</h:link>
```

In other words what is the programmatic equivalent of the above JSF markup?

```
HtmlOutputLink link = new HtmlOutputLink(); // link.? = "Edit"?
// link.? = "edit"?
// link.? = 500?
```

Comment: You can request.setParameter()? Because basically f:param is doing exactly that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code example is confusing. The [`<h:outputLink>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputLink.html) does not have an `outcome` attribute at all, instead its `value` attribute represents the URL. Perhaps you meant to use [`<h:link>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html)?

In any way, you can create `<f:param>` programmatically by just creating an instance of [`UIParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIParameter.html) and adding it as a child of the link component. Here's a kickoff example, assuming that you really wanted to use `<h:link>`.

```
HtmlOutcomeTargetLink link = new HtmlOutcomeTargetLink();
link.setValue("Edit");
link.setOutcome("edit");
UIParameter param = new UIParameter();
param.setName("id");
param.setValue("500");
link.getChildren().add(param);
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I'm new to the JSF world and didn't know of the existence of <h:link>. Many thanks - your solution works....